# How to pass vararg as parameter to method?

Tags: java, oop, variadic-functions

I have a constructor which will need to have vararg of strings as parameter. 
I need to separate those Strings and add them in ArrayList that part will do my method.

Here is the code:

```
private ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
private int index;

public Text(String ... str)
{
    separateVararg(); // How to pass vararg in here
}
```

How to pass this vararg from constructor as a parameter to method ?

Answer (score 3):

vararg is just a convenience syntax for being able to call it like `Text()`, `Text("a")` or `Text("a", "b")`.
In the method it is essentially a `String[]`.
So if you need it as list, just do `Arrays.asList(str)`.
To add all but duplicates to your `answers` list, just use an intermediate `Set` like `answers.addAll(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str)));`
To iterate over the elements and do individual checks, just use a for-each loop over the `str` array, or over the `Set` if you want to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `String`(s) to the `List` and access that instead,

```
public Text(String... str)
{
    answers.addAll(Arrays.asList(str));
}
```

Then you can access `answers` to get your `String`(s).

Comment: I dont want to add all elements from vararg to list, i need to do some checks first, such as to see if there are some same strings in it.

Comment: Then iterate the `String`(s) and test each one, if it meets your criteria add it to the `List`.